# How to detect all links within a div, on mouseover

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, svelte

In a Svelte app I'm trying to detect when the user is hovering over a link, within a `div`. I've added a `mouseover` event listener to the `div`, and am checking if the element is a link, but this is too simplistic: it doesn't detect links that contain HTML tags.

Example code, also [available as REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ddb8722ae7894070a7845e767d86c8c1?version=3.44.3):

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    let container;
    
    onMount(() => {
    container.addEventListener('mouseover', async (event) => {
            if (event.target.tagName !== 'A') return;
            console.log(event.target.attributes['href'].value);
        });
    });
</script>

<div bind:this={container}>
    <a href="https://www.example.com">Hello World</a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com"><strong>Hello World</strong></a>
</div>
```

The problem is that second link: hovering over it the target is the `strong` tag, not the `a` tag. So, how can I reliably detect all links within the container `div`, without having to add an event listener to every individual link?

Comment: Just for your information you can directly use the `on:mouseover` directive. Check more about it [here](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives).

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed a lot nicer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the target, use `.closest('a')` to navigate to the enclosing `<a>` element, if any. (If the element that the event was dispatched to is an `<a>`, it'll be returned.)

```
container.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
    const a = event.target.closest('a');
    if (a) console.log(a.href);
});
```

```js
container.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
  const a = event.target.closest('a');
  if (a) console.log(a.href);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="https://www.example.com">Hello World</a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com"><strong>Hello World</strong></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the container to a variable and setting the listener inside onMount you could also set it in Svelte directly on the element like this

```
<script>        
    function handleMouseover() {
        const a = event.target.closest('a')
        if(a) console.log(a.href);
    };
</script>

<div on:mouseover={handleMouseover}>
    <a href="/path">Hello World</a>
    <a href="https://www.example.com"><strong>Hello World</strong></a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's correct but wasn't really the problem. So instead of posting a new version of  @CertainPerformance's answer, I would recommand you to just notify the poster or the answer of this improvement (just like I just did).